# Alternative solution to Cumulative Cardinality Aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, aws-elasticsearch

I'm running an Elasticsearch cluster that doesn't have access to `x-packs` on AWS, but I'd still like to do a [`cumulative cardinality aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-cardinality-aggregation.html) to determine the daily counts of new users to my site.

Is there an alternate solution to this problem?

For example, how could I transform:

```
GET /user_hits/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_users": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        },
        "total_new_users": {
          "cumulative_cardinality": {
            "buckets_path": "distinct_users" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To produce the same result without `cumulative_cardinality`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cumulative cardinality was added precisely for that reason -- it wasn't easily calculable before...

As with almost anything in ElasticSearch, though, there's a script to get it done for ya. Here's my take on it.

1. Set up an index

```json
PUT user_hits
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Add 1 new user in one day and 2 more the day after, one of which is not strictly 'new'.

```json
POST user_hits/_doc
{"user_id":1,"timestamp":"2020-10-01"}

POST user_hits/_doc
{"user_id":1,"timestamp":"2020-10-02"}

POST user_hits/_doc
{"user_id":3,"timestamp":"2020-10-02"}
```

3. Mock a date histogram using a parametrized start + number of day, group the users accordingly, and then compare the days' results vis-à-vis

```json
GET /user_hits/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2020-10-01"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "new_users_count_vs_prev_day": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": """
          state.by_day_map = [:];
          state.start_millis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(params.start_date).getTime();
          state.day_millis = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
          state.dt_formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        """,
        "map_script": """
          for (def step = 1; step < params.num_of_days + 1; step++) {
            def timestamp = doc.timestamp.value.millis;
            def user_id = doc['user_id'].value;
            def anchor = state.start_millis + (step * state.day_millis);
            // add a `n__` prefix to more easily sort the resulting map later on
            def anchor_pretty = step + '__' + state.dt_formatter.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(anchor));
            
            if (timestamp <= anchor) {
              if (state.by_day_map.containsKey(anchor_pretty)) {
                state.by_day_map[anchor_pretty].add(user_id);
              } else {
                state.by_day_map[anchor_pretty] = [user_id];
              }
            }
        }
        """,
        "combine_script": """
            List keys=new ArrayList(state.by_day_map.keySet());
            Collections.sort(keys);
          
            def unique_sorted_map = new TreeMap();
            def unique_from_prev_day = [];
            
            for (def key : keys) { 
              def unique_users_per_day = new HashSet(state.by_day_map.get(key));
              
              unique_users_per_day.removeIf(user -> unique_from_prev_day.contains(user));
              
               // remove the `n__` prefix
               unique_sorted_map.put(key.substring(3), unique_users_per_day.size());
               unique_from_prev_day.addAll(unique_users_per_day);
            }
            return unique_sorted_map
        """,
        "reduce_script": "return states",
        "params": {
          "start_date": "2020-10-01",
          "num_of_days": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```json
"aggregations" : {
  "new_users_count_vs_prev_day" : {
    "value" : [
      {
        "2020-10-01" : 1,    <-- 1 new unique user            
        "2020-10-02" : 1,    <-- another new unique user
        "2020-10-03" : 0,
        "2020-10-04" : 0,
        "2020-10-05" : 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The script is guaranteed to be slow but has one, potentially quite useful, **advantage** -- you can adjust it to return the full list of new user IDs, not just the count that you'd get from the cumulative cardinality which, [according to its implementation's author](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/43661#issuecomment-507731567), only works in a sequential, cumulative manner by design.

Comment: I agree, very complex - but a workable solution and a great answer - thanks!