# Alternative to ElasticSearch's cumulative cardinality in AWS Opensearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

For some reason, I'm unable to use the aggregation type `cumulative_cardinality` in AWS Opensearch. I looked around in the documentation and couldn't find it mentioned anywhere. Is there something I'm missing or Opensearch doesn't support this function? Moreover, is there any way (a plugin maybe) that I can use to access this functionality in Opensearch?

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown aggregation type [cumulative_cardinality]",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 384
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown aggregation type [cumulative_cardinality]",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 384,
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "named_object_not_found_exception",
      "reason": "[1:384] unknown field [cumulative_cardinality]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336811/alternative-solution-to-cumulative-cardinality-aggregation-in-elasticsearch) but this will effect the performance.